# Reporting Services - When does your custom assembly requires permissions?

Tags: .net, reporting-services

I made an example of a custom assembly which tries to read a text file on my local computer. I want to show the result of the text file in my SSRS report. I know that Reporting Services needs to ask for permissions to access the text file on my computer, this by changing the configuration file **rspreviewpolicy.config**. This is all based on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/extensions/secure-development/understanding-security-policies?view=sql-server-ver15).

Now, I've made another custom assembly in which:

- A: I use the **System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode** in a function to make an URL
- B: I use the built-in SSRS functions like parameters. In a function I want to hide the column names based on the selected column name values in my multiselection parameter. Basically, it has to fetch all the parameter values in my function. This uses the **Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingObjectModel** assembly which is located in the CommonExtensions folder of SSRS.

The thing is that I don't have to change anything now to my configuration file **rspreviewpolicy.config** to run my report without problems using my custom assembly? It doesn't state that I don't need permissions or whatsoever?

**My real question is: when do I know for which assemblies/namespace I have to ask for permissions? To read a text file using System.IO.StreamReader I need permissions but for System.WebHttpUtility.UrlEncode I don't?**